# Pass a var from a filter to another function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to pass a product ID that is stored as var inside a filter to another function.

I tried this and it doesn't pass the ID:

**PHP**

```
$has_option_id = null;

function wc_add_to_cart_message_filter($message, $product_id = null) {
    $GLOBALS['has_option_id'] = $product_id;
    return $message;
}
add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_filter', 10, 2 );

function above_cart_js() {
    $product_id = $GLOBALS['has_option_id'];
    echo $product_id; // Outputs NULL (nothing)
}
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'above_cart_js', 5 );
```

Is there a way to pass the ID to the other function?

Comment: Please try this and let me know what it prints out: Put this to   above_cart_js() function.   $GLOBALS['sample_variation"] =1;  And this one to wc_add_to_cart_message_filter() function:  echo $GLOBALS['sample_variation"] ;  - And let me know if it prints "1" or Null.   This would help us to understand whether these two hooks run at the same http request or not.

Comment: @ElvinHaci I had to add it to the `return` var, since `echo` doesn't work inside filters. But still, it returned nothing (or NULL).

Comment: If none of them is able to pass global variable to each other, it means they don't run at the same request.  wc_add_to_cart_message  triggers when you add some product to your cart - and that mostly run via  AJAX.  Meanwhile woocommerce_before_cart is an action which runs inside cart page template. So it gets that they live in different places. You need to use another logic. Or if you explain what you need exactly and why you do this, may be we can give better suggestions

Comment: @ElvinHaci Ok I see, that makes sence. I need to get the ID of the item that was just added to the cart to display a custom message (wich is different for each product) outside the message box. That's why I'm trying to get the ID to the hook.

Comment: ok i am adding the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your given action and filter don't runt at the same HTTP request, they can't global variable to each other. One of them is usually run by AJAX, another in is just Cart Template Hook. So, you can do it by Cookie Storage. First store just added product ID to Cookie, then get it from there.

```
function wc_add_to_cart_message_filter($message, $product_id = null) {
  setcookie('just_added_product', array_keys($product_id)[0], time() + (600), "/"); 
  return $message;
}
add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_filter', 10, 2 );

function above_cart_js() {
  echo $_COOKIE["just_added_product"]; 
}
add_action ( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'above_cart_js', 5 );
```

Comment: Had to change `array_keys($product_id)[0]` to just `$product_id` but then it works, thanks!

Comment: That difference is because your filter is wc_add_to_cart_message (which is deprecated filter), while my one is wc_add_to_cart_message_html. Anyway, i am glad it is solved.